# LVM restore wrong meta file?

Tags: backup, lvm

1. I added the wrong file instead-of original file.

   ```
   vgcfgrestore -f /tmp/vg00.backup /dev/rdsk/c0t4d0
   ```
2. But i did

   ```
   vgcfgrestore -f /tmp/vg01.backup /dev/rdsk/c0t4d0
   ```

Now my volume shows  volumes in your group.

Any possible to recover my data. 
I am relaying panic, How to restore the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did restored a wrong configuration to /dev/rdsk/c0t4d0. But dont forget /dev/rdsk/c0t4d0 is added to some VG with some LV's but greatnews they have not mounted and they dont have any data.

1. Remove all LV's with lvremove
2. Remove VG with vgremove.

Then  do `vgcfgrestore -f /tmp/vg00.backup /dev/rdsk/c0t4d0` again.

Let me know if any issues.

Hope it helps.

Comment: my data will be recoverable ??

Comment: @mahendra you just made a partition schema , not data restoring.

Comment: In the Volume have more than 1TB Data. I want to restore back .

Comment: the above cli doesnot work. Any other options

Comment: Actually i use the above cli after the command. pvcreate , So new volume overwrite the old volume. So how to recover it ???